# react-redux does not produce output value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm following the full stack django-react assembly guide from https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-ii-be9cf6942957.  Of note, this link is one of three parts of a main article.

What I'm trying to do is prove the `/api/echo` response works.  in `app.js`, it calls for the function `this.props.fetchMessage('Hi!');` and the expectation is that state would get updated with a `state.message` value, which would return to props using the redux `connect` library.

However, {this.props.message} does not populate and is not shown on the screen.  I even copied it right from the cookbook here:  https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/_articles/redux_jwt_auth/frontend

I'm trying to learn React, redux, and Django.  Of note, I have checked and the /api/echo response is coming in as expected. (using the browser developer bar to confirm).

What am I missing to ensure that this.props.message is being filled in?  Thanks.

## actions/echo.js

```
import { RSAA } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import { withAuth } from '../reducers';

export const ECHO_REQUEST = '@@echo/ECHO_REQUEST';
export const ECHO_SUCCESS = '@@echo/ECHO_SUCCESS';
export const ECHO_FAILURE = '@@echo/ECHO_FAILURE';

export const echo = (message) => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '/api/echo/',
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({message: message}),
        headers: withAuth({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        types: [
            ECHO_REQUEST, ECHO_SUCCESS, ECHO_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

## reducers/echo.js

```
import * as echo from '../actions/echo'

const initialState = {
    message: ""
}

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case echo.ECHO_SUCCESS:
            return {
                message: action.payload.message
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const serverMessage = (state) => state.message;
```

## reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import auth, * as fromAuth from './auth.js'
import echo, * as fromEcho from './echo.js'

export default combineReducers({
    auth: auth,
    echo: echo,
    router: routerReducer
})


export const isAuthenticated = state => fromAuth.isAuthenticated(state.auth)
export const accessToken = state => fromAuth.accessToken(state.auth)
export const isAccessTokenExpired = state => fromAuth.isAccessTokenExpired(state.auth)
export const refreshToken = state => fromAuth.refreshToken(state.auth)
export const isRefreshTokenExpired = state => fromAuth.isRefreshTokenExpired(state.auth)
export const authErrors = state => fromAuth.errors(state.auth)
export const serverMessage = state => fromEcho.serverMessage(state.echo)

export function withAuth(headers={}) {
    return (state) => ({
        ...headers,
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken(state)}`
    })
}
```

## app.js

This is where the `fetchMessage` function is populated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {echo} from './actions/echo';
import { serverMessage } from './reducers/echo';


class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage('Hi!');
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.message);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
                <p>Message:  {this.props.message}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({ message: serverMessage(state)}),
    { fetchMessage: echo }
)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `appState` object passed to `mapStateToProps`, which you are providing to your `serverMessage` selector function, is not the slice of app state managed by a single reducer. [It's the global Redux store state](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments).

you probably want this in reducers/echo.js :

```
export const serverMessage = (state) => state.echo.message;
```

Comment: wow.  ok.  still trying to decypher this framework.  Thanks much.  This works.

Comment: as mentioned in another answer, an alternate solution is to use the selector functions defined in `reducers/index.js` as they seem to be what the author of your cookbook intended.  Using them might make it a little more clear that selectors act on the entire state and not any particular slice of it.

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong import `import { serverMessage } from './reducers/echo';`

Selector from root reducer need to be used  `import { serverMessage } from './reducers/';` Only root reducer keeps information how different part of substate are mapped.